# Active y Hover se juntan

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo una website. Cuando una pagina esta activa, el boton de esa pagina se vuelve azul oscuro. He introducido un `dropdown-button` y me esta dando bastantes problemas. Cuando el boton Multimedia (dropdown-button) esta en activo, el hover no para, cosa que con los otros botones no pasa. Aqui el ejemplo: https://gyazo.com/4e9200345901ae17acfb71936030235f

Aqui el CSS y HTML:

```css
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size:30px;
 
}





li a.active {
    background-color: #309ba5;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #4dd6e2;
    color: white;
}
button:hover {
   background-color: #4dd6e2;
    color: white;
}
.dropbtn {
    background: #e0e0e0 url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png') no-repeat 0;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
 position:fixed;
 left: 9px;
 top:148px;
 width: 210px;
 height: 55px;
}
.dropbtn_active {
    color: white;
 background: #309ba5 url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png') no-repeat 0;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
 position:fixed;
 left: 9px;
 top:148px;
 width: 210px;
 height: 55px;
}

.active {    
  background-color: #309ba5;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 190px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
 position: fixed;
 top: 170px;
 left: 220px;
 background-color: #ededed;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size:27px;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #e2e2e2}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn_active">Multimedia</button>
  
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="mp4.html">MP4</a>
    <a href="png.html">PNG</a>
    <a href="gif.html">GIF</a>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn_active')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: creo que deberias reformular tu pregunta anterior para contener esto tambien .. hacer 2 preguntas es innecesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que sea porque tienes conflictos en el CSS:

Tienes puesto esto:

```
button:hover {
    background-color: #4dd6e2;
    color: white;
}
```

Y esto:

```
.dropbtn_active {
    color: white;
    background: #309ba5 url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png') no-repeat 0;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    color: black;
    ...}
```

En la misma etiqueta le pones varios colores a lo mismo y estás dando estilos por elementos y por clase distintos.

Deberías limpiar el código de todo lo que no hace falta y eliminar los conflictos para no tener resultados inesperados.

**EDITO**

Una forma rápida de hacerlo sería:

```
.dropbtn_active {
  background: #309ba5 url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png') no-repeat 0;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  color: black;
  ...}

.dropbtn_active:hover {
  background-color: #4dd6e2;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Me podrias dar un ejemplo de como tendria que ser? Porque no lo entiendo del todo. Gracias

Comment: Eliminas el estilo de `button:hover` y añades el cambio de color en `.dropbtn_active:hover`. Voy a añadirlo a la respuesta.

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo si hago esto

Comment: He mirado tu video pero no veo el problema que llamas _"no para"_. Si me lo explicas mejor quizás vea alguna otra solución.

Comment: Como puedes ver en el video en los primeros segundos, cuando el boton "Home" esta activo (azul oscuro), si pongo el raton encima, no se activa el    hover. Sin embargo, en el boton Multimedia cuando esta activo, el hover sigue funcionando.

Comment: Usa lo mismo que has usado en los `li`: `.dropbtn_active:hover:not(.active)` en vez de sólo el `hover`